# Jquery removeAttr, prop, attr not working for 'required' property

Tags: jquery, required

Good day, I am reaching out to everyone who has encountered difficulties and resolved issues related to the 'required' property of html form components. In my case, the 'required' property doesn't seem to update whenever I try to modify or set it using removeAttr, attr or prop methods.

Note: the removeAttr for the 'placeholder' property works, however for 'required' it doesn't.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select#decision").on('change', function() {
    var decValue = $("select#decision").val();

    if (decValue == 'For STR') {
      $("textarea#addtl_reason").prop('required', true);
      $("textarea#add_notes").removeAttr('placeholder');
      $("#sos").slideDown();
      $("#reason").slideDown();
      $("#narrative").slideDown();
    } 
    else {
      $("textarea#addtl_reason").removeAttr('required');
      $("#sos").slideUp();
      $("#reason").slideUp();
      $("#narrative").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "narrative" class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label class="control-label col-md-5" for="addtl_reason">STR Narrative</label>
  
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <textarea cam-variable-name="addtl_reason"
              cam-variable-type="String"
              id="addtl_reason"
              maxlength="4000"
              class="form-control glow"
              rows="5"
              aria-describedby="notesHelpBlock"
              placeholder="Write your case narrative here..."
              onkeyup="cnt_reason_character()"
              autofocus></textarea>

    <small id="notesHelpBlock" class="form-text pull-right text-muted"> <span id="words_count" class="d-none form-text text-muted"> <span id="reason_textcount">0</span> / 4000</span></small>
    <small id="notesHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">Provide your case narrative here.</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! But there is no ``select#decision`` and no event handler ``cnt_reason_character()``...

Comment: Hi! thank you for your response. cnt_reason_character() is a function which I have not included here (sorry) as for the 'select#decision' it still works the same as '#decision', just been trying out things. I think what's weird in the behavior is why removeAttr() not working for the 'required' attribute in this case the textarea but it doesn't work for other components as well. But when when I try it on other attribs such as placeholder, it does.

Comment: Also tried attr() and prop() to set/remove the 'required' property but still doesn't work. Do you know any present issues with these jquery methods for the 'required' property?

Comment: to add on the '#decision' this actually references a change on a 'select' html component. The goal is depending on the option selected, it will set/remove the 'required' property on the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Try vanilla JavaScript:

```
.setAttribute('required', true/false);
.removeAttribute('required');
.toggleAttribute('required');
```

If you use vanilla JavaScript methods on a jQuery object, it will not recognize it. So you either use JavaScript methods to reference an element (recommended) or de-reference the jQuery object:

```
// Two ways to de-referencing a jQuery object
$('input')[0]
//OR
$('input').get(0)
```

The zero indicates that you are targeting the first one only so if you already know that it's the second input use index 1.

```js
// Using no ids, classes, or tagnames just indexes
document.forms[0].elements[1].onclick = e => 
  e.target.previousElementSibling.toggleAttribute('required');
  
// De-referencing the second .data 
$('.data')[1].setAttribute('required', true);
```

```css
[required] {
  outline: 3px dashed red
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name='data' class='data'><input type='button' value='Toggle'><br>
  <input name='data' class='data'><br>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Just some advice, the attributes you are removing are not commonly removed because of their nature. A `placeholder` never needs to be removed because it disappears when the user focuses on a form control. `required` shouldn't be removed because it facilitates validation. Why would you need to remove them?

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer. For your last question, in the form I'm trying to create there are certain fields that needs to be flexible in terms of the required attributed depending on the choice selected in the dropdown.

Comment: for example, if I have opt 1 and opt 2 in my select component and fields 1 and 1, if I select opt 1, field 1 should be required and field 2 shouldn't. The same logic goes when opt 2 is selected (field 1 not required, field 2 required).

Comment: sorry that should be * fields 1 and 2

Comment: Ok, I see, why the `required` what about `placeholder`? BTW, have you tried applying my answer? I think `.toggleAttribute()` may be the most useful method for your situation.